# Why bindValue or BindParam doesn't modify the prepared statement?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, bindvalue, bindparam

Using latest php in order to create a function that adds a row to table user.

```
class targil_db {

    private $_pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        // username: root password: <blank> database: targil
        $this->_pdo = new PDO(
                    'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=targil',
                    'root',
                    ''
                    );
    }

function addUser($username, $password) {

    $md5password = md5($password);
    $sql = <<<SQL
        "INSERT INTO user (username,password) VALUES (:username,:password)"
SQL;

    $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}

}
```

when I execute the addUser function, this is the query that i see executed on the mysql log file:

```
INSERT INTO user (username,password) VALUES (:username,:password)
```

as you can see it did not replace the :varname into the proper value.
what am i missing ?

I tried both bindValue and bindParam but I got the same results.

## update

even when i change `:username` and `:password` to `?,?` and i use
`bindValue(1,$username)` and `bindValue(2,$password)` i get the same results.
the query that get executed actually still has `?,?` in it instead of the actual variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 $sql = <<<SQL
    "INSERT INTO user (username,password) VALUES (:username,:password)"
SQL;
```

should be:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO user (username,password) VALUES (:username,:password)
SQL;
```

I needed to remove the double quotes, i already used `<<<SQL` to start the string and `SQL;` to stop it.

Comment: actually with bigger qeuries when the query is fixed and there is no extra double quotes the bind functions don't work.

Comment: welp but i guess that's for a different question.